# How can I define a widget using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, yii

My dialogue code is following..

```
<?php 
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
'id'=>'pagetemplate',
'options'=>array(
'title'=>'Page Template',
'autoOpen'=>false,
'modal'=>true,
'width'=>1000,
'height'=>300           
),
));?>
```

when a javascript function CLICK is calling  , i want to define this code under click function. how can i convert this to javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiDialog) and for working demo you can refer [here](http://demo.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework/cjuidialog)

```
    $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
    'id'=>'mydialog',
    // additional javascript options for the dialog plugin
    'options'=>array(
        'title'=>'Dialog box 1',
        'autoOpen'=>false,
    ),
));

    echo 'dialog content here';

$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');

// the link that may open the dialog
echo CHtml::link('open dialog', '#', array(
   'onclick'=>'$("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;',

    ));
```

For your instance

```
<a href='#' onClick ='click();' ><img src='". Yii::app()->baseURL.'/images/templateicon.png'."' width=10% height=5% /></a>.
```

so now I write a javascript function

```
    <script>
    function click(){
      $("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;
}
    </script>
```

Comment: <a href='#' onClick ='click();' ><img src='". Yii::app()->baseURL.'/images/templateicon.png'."' width=10% height=5%  /></a>. when i click on this anchor tag i have to open a widget. So under this javascript function i have to execute this widget code..that is under click function...Help me please..thanks in advance...